# How to used flush() or any other appropriate function to see the output of echo

Tags: php

I have following php code that sends sms to contact numbers using some api

```
function send_sms($composedSmsMessage, $contactNumber) {

    // some cURL function here to send SMS

    echo "SMS sent to:" . $contactNumber . "<br>";
    return 1;
}
$composedSmsMessage = "Welcome back...";
foreach ($newContacts as $newContact) {
    $contactNumber = $newContact["s_contact_number"];
    $smsStatus = send_sms($composedSmsMessage, $contactNumber);

    // some more functions

    flush();
}
```

How to used flush() or any other appropriate function to see the text echo by send_sms() function in browser while php is running on server.

Comment: Output is sent once the output buffer is full or the script terminates. You _can_ fllush inbetween (`flush()` or `ob_flush()`) but actually it is up to the browser to decide if the payload it receives is displayed right away or held back.

Comment: You can use `ob_start` to turn on output buffering and after the whole script is done executing use `ob_flush` to flush the contents of the buffer to the client. But if it will work depends on configuration of your server

Comment: Why don't you just return the phrase you want to echo, and use 'echo $smsStatus;' in your `foreach`.

Comment: @RTS There are many other messages produced in send_sms() function that need to be displayed in browser while script is running on the server.

Comment: @The Law, I used combination of ob_start(); ob_flush(); and ob_end_flush(); but unfortunately did't work for me, don't know the reason.

Comment: What server are you using? If nginx and fpm, you won't be able to do this.

Comment: I am using apache2